# App Engine (Python) - POST'ing responses from HTML control arrays

Tags: python, html, google-app-engine, post

Using App Engine (Python), I am trying to POST the values from a variable array of select controls in an HTML form. Each select control is paired with some text about what the user is rating.

For example, "Rate these fruits from 1-5 (1 least, 5 best)", the user is presented with a dynamic form like -

```
<> Apple

<> Bananas

<> Cherries
```

where <> represents an HTML select control (named "fruit_value") where they can choose 1,2,3,4 or 5 for each fruit.

I can return the value of each select control in the POST by using:

```
    fruit_value = self.request.POST.getall('fruit_value')

    for fruit_value_score in zip(fruit_value):
        print '%s<br />' % (fruit_value_score)
```

But how do I know which fruit in the array is being scored? I would like to return the text that matches the select control back to the server side. I tried converting the HTML text to an array of named labels but they don't seem to pass their values in the POST. I also tried a hidden txt control but I can't seem to set the value parameter dynamically inside the for..loop when my page builds. I also tried putting the fruit name into an array of disabled txt boxes but that makes the value not passable in the code (otherwise would be passable if not disabled)

Am I missing something obvious here (how to pass the score along with item being scored?)

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: No, to be more clear, these values are the what the users select in the drop down to rank how they like each fruit in the form. So 5 = love it, 1 = hate it, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Well, yes, you are missing something obvious: they need separate names. You can't call them all the same thing then expect to distinguish between them. You need `<select name="apple_value">`, `<select name="banana_value">`, and so on.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. My problem is the form is dynamic, is it practical to give each select control a unique name value when building the page? If I was using, for example, a select and text box together, my code would fine and I wouldn't need uniquely named controls. Thx again.

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by that. If you had a select and a text box, you still wouldn't be able to tell the difference between them, except that you know that the select only has values 1-5 and the text box could have anything. But if someone put '1' into the text box and selected 2 from the select, you wouldn't know. I also don't understand why building the page dynamically means you can't give them unique names: if you know enough to give them unique labels, you can give them unique names (you could even use the label text as part of the name).

Comment: OK thanks, I'm not explaining my challenge very well but based on your feedback I have a new solution. The original idea was to use the above code to bring back all responses as a set of key-value pairs in the zip, parse them and store them in the db.